# How to delete file by file with batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm wondering how I can make my batch file delete a file one by one in a folder of my choice, and echo each fie deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For your batch file change `%f` to `%%f`

you dont need the touch command it's from gnuwin32 or cygwin, I used it to create 3 files, q w and e.

```
C:\blah>touch q w e<ENTER>

C:\blah>for %f in (*.*) do @(echo deleting %f & del %f)
deleting e
deleting q
deleting w

C:\blah>
```

note- to understand it or do it from scratch try `for %f in (*.*) do echo %f` and one can work it out from there.

Comment: Can you please explain every command on the line "C:\blah>" I'm new too batch and this is a bit confusing

Comment: @Xaxis have you ever opened a cmd prompt and seen it says e.g. `C:\Users\Xaxis>`  are you aware that c:\users\Xaxis is a directory, a folder. And have you tried  `C:\Users\harvey>dir<ENTER>`  and have you tried making a bat file and writing dir in there. and running the batch file.  If you don't even know those basics then you shouldn't be trying to understand cmd's  'for' command.

Comment: I have done those things, but I did a bit of research to further clarify your answer, and ran through it piece by piece. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Xaxis - Use the command `FOR /?` to get information about the for loop.

Comment: @Liturgist err litgurist, The For command is the most complicated command in cmd. If it was the case that he didn't know that you can type `/?` after a command to see the options for it, then he is better off studying a bunch of other commands in more detail before diving into that. (And to call it a for loop is a bit  misleading, because if you do /f with tokens="..." then the body of the for command after the 'do' will only run once. So perhaps one shouldn't call it a for loop.